# Customizing Stripe UI integration to save and fetch user card information

Tags: ios, node.js, firebase, stripe-payments

I am using stripe to allow users to send payments to each other. I have run into an error and I am pretty sure it is because the user doesn't have their payment types saved. I was wondering if it is possible to manipulate stripes STPPaymentOptionsViewController UI to save the customer info? Or if I would have to customize my own controller to do this.

Comment: What customer info do you need so save? Billing address?

Comment: No their credit card!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to store users' credit card information.

On your server, you need to call `stripe.paymentMethods.attach()` method to save a payment method (represented by a `stripeID`, we'll talk about that later).

Example:

```js
app.post('/attach_card', (req, res) => {
    const customerID = req.body.customer_id;
    const cardStripeID = req.body.stripe_id;

    stripe.paymentMethods.attach(
        cardStripeID,
        { customer: customerID }
    ).then(value => {
        res.status(200).send(value);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).end()
    });
});
```

There are two parameters needed for the above code, `customer_id` and `stripe_id`. I assume you are already familiar with `customer_id`, so let's talk about how to gather users' card information and get the `stripe_id` that represents the payment method.

1. Initialize a `STPAddCardViewController` (same UI as the add card screen in `STPPaymentOptionsViewController`)

```swift
let config = STPPaymentConfiguration()
config.requiredBillingAddressFields = .full

let viewController = STPAddCardViewController(configuration: config, theme: STPTheme.default())
viewController.delegate = self

let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

2. Make your ViewController comply to the `STPAddCardViewControllerDelegate`

```swift
func addCardViewControllerDidCancel(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController) {
    // Handle cancel action if needed
}

func addCardViewController(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController, didCreatePaymentMethod paymentMethod: STPPaymentMethod, completion: @escaping STPErrorBlock) {
    completion(nil)
    print("--- created payment method with stripe ID: \(paymentMethod.stripeId)")

    // Call the previous server code to store card info with Alamofire
    let url = YOUR_SERVER_BASE_URL.appendingPathComponent("attach_card")

    AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: [ 
        "customer_id": YOUR_CUSTOMER_ID,
        "stripe_id": paymentMethod.stripeId
    ]) 

    // Dismiss the modally presented VC
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now the card info is saved, and you can view it in your Stripe console:

[image: Stripe console]

---

Stripe documentation:

- [Attach payment method to customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/attach)
- [STPAddCardViewController](https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPAddCardViewController.html)
- [STPAddCardViewControllerDelegate](https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Protocols/STPAddCardViewControllerDelegate.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I apologize for reaching out late! So the customer, I would like them to update their card information on a settings view controller instead of navigating when the user checks out. Could I manipulate that there?

Comment: No worries. Yes, as I mentioned in my answer, you can manually instantiate a `STPAddCardViewController`. You can consult the 1st sectino of [this tutorial](https://therightsw.com/stripe-ios-integration/) about how to instantiate the VC.

Comment: Thank you! Im thinking that this was not my issue. I am still running into an error.

Comment: So saving users' card info did not help?

Comment: yes it did! Helped me understand more. However, I am still seeing the same issue error that brought me here. I may have to ask another question. However you did answer the question I asked.

Comment: Glad to hear that! In the mean time, could you mark this answer as accepted as it solved this particular issue? Thanks! I'll definitely look into your new question later.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that's a usecase that Stripe can support, so you may want to reach out to them to confirm: https://support.stripe.com/contact/email

Comment: Thanks for replying. It is a service provided by stripe I have reached out to them and here is the link that describes being able to collect payments and send them to users. [https://stripe.com/en-br/connect/payouts]  However, let's throw this to the side for now. My issue is I am wondering if it is possible to manipulate the UI to save the credit card info or if I have to create my own.